# What does "purpose" mean in "because of his own purpose and grace"? 2 Timothy 1:9

Tags: word-study

**2 Timothy 1:9**

> "who saved us and called us to a holy calling, not because of our works but because of his own **purpose** and grace, which he gave us in Christ Jesus". ESV My emphasis.

Purpose. "prothesin" here is singular. Is it refering to "purpose" in general, everything having purpose, or one supreme purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that "**purpose**" or "prothesin" is the singular purpose that Paul describes elsewhere in Ephesians, speaking of ***praising God for His grace***:

> "Blessed is the **God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ**, who has
> blessed us with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly realms in
> Christ.  4 **For he chose us in Christ before the foundation of the
> world** that we should be holy and blameless before him in love.
>
> 5 He did this by predestining us to adoption as his legal heirs
> through Jesus Christ, according to the pleasure of his will— 6 **to the
> praise of the glory of his grace** that he has freely bestowed on us in
> his dearly loved Son.
>
> 7 In him we have redemption through his blood, the forgiveness of our
> offenses, according to the riches of his grace  8 that he lavished on
> us in all wisdom and insight.
>
> 9 He did this when he revealed to us the mystery of his will,
> according to his good pleasure that he set forth in Christ,
>
> 10 toward the administration of the fullness of the times, to head up
> all things in Christ—the things in heaven and the things on earth. 11
> In Christ we too have been claimed as God’s own possession, since we
> were predestined according to the purpose of him who accomplishes all
> things according to the counsel of his will  12 so that we, who were
> the first to set our hope on Christ, would be **to the praise of his
> glory**.
>
> 13 And when you heard the word of truth (the gospel of your
> salvation)—when you believed in Christ—you were marked with the seal
> of the promised Holy Spirit, 14 who is the down payment of our
> inheritance, until the redemption of God’s own possession, **to the
> praise of his glory**.

A few things to note from Ephesians compared to your text presented:

**1.)** God's **purpose** is tied with Him who "...**saved us and called us to a holy calling**..."

**2.)** This  saving and calling is "**...not because of our works...**"

**3.)** I am contending that this **purpose** is directly related to the praise of the glory of His grace (**Ephesians 1:6**) which is given to us in Christ before the ages began (**2 Timothy 1:9**), which in Ephesians 1 is clarified as "**before the foundation of the world**."

I believe that is the one **supreme purpose** to which you asked, that God is working towards.

Romans 8:28 mentions the word purpose too, the concept is the same and the word "prothesin" is used here as well.

It would appear that in conjunction with Ephesians 1, Romans 8:28-30 is the primary "**purpose**", this can be seen in the following terms:

**1.)** God works everything together for good to those who love God(true believers) to those who are called according to His purpose(those who are predestined and chosen in Christ before the world began (**Ephesians 1:4-6**).

**2.)** God intends that His predestined people be conformed to the image of His Son, Jesus Christ.  (**Rom 8:29**)

**3.)** Those whom God predestined, He also called them, justified them, and glorified them.  (**Rom 8:30**)

> "And we know that all things work together for good for those who love
> God, **who are called according to his purpose**,
>
> 29 because those whom he foreknew he also predestined to be conformed
> to the image of his Son, that his Son would be the firstborn among
> many brothers and sisters.
>
> 30 And those he predestined, he also called; and those he called, he
> also justified; and those he justified, he also glorified."

Romans 8:28-30 is related to Ephesians 1:3-14 & 2 Timothy 1:9 because Grace & salvation are involved in each of these verses.  For example:

**1.)** 2 Tim 1:9 mentions: “saved us and called us to a holy calling“ this relates to the same calling in Romans 8:28 & 8:30.

**2.)** 2 Timothy 1:9 mentions: “his own purpose and grace” which is connected with the themes of Grace in Ephesians chapters 1 & 2.  God’s purpose can be seen in 2 ways: **1st**: God works this salvation/adoption/Grace according to the counsel of His own will (Ephesians 1:11)

**2nd**: God’s purpose as already outlined above can be understood to be a mystery to us.  In other words we may not fully grasp why God chose to be glorified in the salvation of sinners through the death of His Son, yet, that’s what Ephesians 1 clearly shows.

**CONCLUSION**

God's grace was given to us in Christ, before the world began(**2 Timothy 1:9**), that we might praise Him for such grace (**Ephesians 1:6**); that is the ultimate **purpose** I would argue, and having such grace we might also be conformed to the image of Christ to the praise of His glory. (**Ephesians 1:12,14**, **Rom 8:29,30)**.

That is the understanding of **2 Timothy 1:9** as it relates to Gods **purpose** with our receiving of Grace & being saved.

The **difference** from **2 Timothy 1:9** to **Ephesians 1:1-14** is that Paul gives us a snapshot of God’s purpose being briefly explained to Timothy, & Paul then makes ***the purpose*** more clear in Ephesians 1.

Comment: @C.Stroud Made some edits, if I lost you again; I’m open to correction.

Comment: Clearer Especially as you put "the purpose" +1

Answer (score 1):

> who did save us, and did call with an holy calling, not according to our works, but according to His own purpose and grace, that was given to us in Christ Jesus, before the times of the ages, 2: Tim. 1:9

Op asked; "Is it referring to "purpose" in general, everything having purpose, or one supreme purpose?"

This is a specific purpose for those who have been called out according to God's purpose alone.

This calling is holy, which means set a part for God's purpose.  His calling has nothing to do with our acts but was given to us before time began.  Before we had a choice.  It's God's choice according to His purpose.  This does not have to do with a evangel of the circumcision Where God's calling to the people of Israel is clearly associated with the act of repentance and works of righteousness to enter into the kingdom of heaven's.

Our calling is not "In accord with our acts".  It is in accord with God's grace given to us before The ages even began.

Pretty amazing this calling and purpose of God happened before Adam was ever created!

This is where God intends to display in us the transcendent riches of his grace.  Eph. 2:7

> Even being dead in the trespasses, did make us to live together with the Christ, (by grace ye are having been saved,) 6and did raise [us] up together, and did seat [us] together in the heavenly [places] in Christ Jesus, 7that He might show, in the ages that are coming, the exceeding riches of His grace in kindness toward us in Christ Jesus, 8for by grace ye are having been saved, through faith, and this not of you — of God the gift, 9not of works,

His work of grace, transcends Any grace that has ever been shown. 2. intransitive, to transcend, surpass, exceed, excel.

He also will be displaying the multifarious wisdom of God is to be made known to the sovereignty's and authorities among the Celestials, through the ecclesia ,His body.

> there might be made known now to the principalities and the authorities in the heavenly [places], through the Assembly, the manifold wisdom of God, 11ACCORDING To the PURPOSE of the AGES which He made in Christ Jesus our Lord,  Ephesians 3:10

This purpose has to do with particular calling (Unknown, secret, mystery) like Israel has a calling on earth; it will become a light to the nations. There is also called out ones that are part of Christ's body that will be fitted to the heavenly realm.  This will be Christ's complement in the heavenly realm.

Comment: You say "This purpose has to do with...." I am still wondering if we can say something even stronger e.g. This purpose is...".

Comment: think the ultimate purpose of God is stated in Ephesians. 
Having made know to us His will, according to His good pleasure, that He purposed in Himself, in regard to the dispensation of the fulness of the times, to bring into one the whole in the Christ, both the things in the heavens, and the things upon the earth — in him; 
This word purpose also means shew bread.  4286. prothesis:
A setting forth, The showbread.  
"purposefully set forth") – properly, providence – literally, "a setting forth in advance for a specific purpose ("God's pre-thesis").   The Showbread was always before Him.

Comment: I've often wondered if that is a symbol of the purpose of God to unite all things in heaven and earth together in Christ.
That is the purpose of God is to unite all  things in heaven and earth in Christ.

Comment: "to unite all things in him", things that are already in Christ are separate because some are "things in heaven and [some] things on earth" Eph 1:10. Possible meaning?

Comment: @C.Stroud, Here's are few other translations I think are helpful in determining all things in Heaven and earth that will be coming under the headship of Christ with regard to the fulfillment of the times [that is, the end of history, the climax of the ages]—to bring all things together in Christ, [both] things in the heavens and things on the earth.   This plan, which God will complete when the time is right, is to bring all creation together, everything in heaven and on earth, with Christ as head.  To have an administration of the complement of the eras, to head up the universe in the Christ.

Comment: - In the heavens as well as on the earth.  Colossians 1:15-20 is what I think is the possible meaning of everything under Christ's headship as well as Phil:2:10, 1 Cor: 15:27-28, Heb:1:8. Ephesians reveals the Transcendent grace given to those whom He purposed in Christ before time began to be God's adopted son's along with Christ as His administration of the heading of all things up that will take place in the fullness of times.  Oh that we might know the hope of our calling as stated a
Ephesians 1:18.

Answer (score 1):

The operative word in 2 Tim 1:9 is πρόθεσις (prothesis) meaning "purpose" or "intention" here.  It occurs just 12 times in the NT.  Of these, God's purpose is mentioned in the following:

- Rom 8:28 - And we know that God works all things together for the good of those who love Him, who are called according to His **purpose**.
- Rom 9:11 - Yet, before the twins were born or had done anything good or bad—in order that God’s purpose in election might stand:
- Eph 1:11 - In him we have obtained an inheritance, having been predestined according to the **purpose** of him who works all things according to the counsel of his will,
- Eph 3:11 - This was according to the eternal **purpose** that he has realized in Christ Jesus our Lord,
- 2 Tim 1:9 - He has saved us and called us to a holy calling, not because of our works, but by His own **purpose** and by the grace He granted us in Christ Jesus before time began.

Thus, God's purpose or intention was to offer His only Son, Jesus, to save humanity:

- John 12:32, “I [Jesus] … will draw all people to myself.”
- John 12:47, “… for I did not come to judge the world but to save the world.”
- Acts 17:30, “God … commands all people everywhere to repent.”
- Rom 3:23, 24, “… for all have sinned … and all are freely forgiven...”
- 1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Savior, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
- 1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”
- 1 Tim 4:10, For to this end we toil and strive, because we have our hope set on the living God, who is the Savior of all people, especially of those who believe.
- Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to all people.”
- Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honor because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.”
- 2 Peter 3:9, “The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness.  He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.”
- 1 John 2:2, “He Himself [Jesus] is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours [Christians to whom John writes] only but also for the whole world.”
- Isa 53:6, “We all like sheep have gone astray … and the LORD has laid on him the iniquity of us all.”

Thus, God's eternal purpose or intention or desire is that all people be saved by grace.